# How to stop using $scope as a naughty store for global variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The following function pops up a modal to ask the user a question:

```
 function askuser(question,options,callback) {
     $scope.question = question;
     $scope.options = options;
     $scope.callback = callback;
     $scope.askusermodal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(
          '<ion-modal-view>\
          <ion-content>{{question}}\
            <div ng-repeat="answer in options"><button class="button" ng-click="askusermodal.hide();callback(answer)">{{answer}}</button></div>\
            </ion-content>\
            </ion-modal-view>', {
        scope: $scope
      });
     $scope.askusermodal.show(); 
 }
```

The use of the global scope service to store inputs to what should be a self contained function feels really wrong, but without doing so, I am not sure how (within the constraints of ionic) to create a different scope to pass to askusermodal, nor how to close the modal from ng-click.

In short how do I rewrite this to stop using global `$scope`?

Comment: I would consider using directives. One for ionic modal, which isolates creating modals from its content (that would be a generic one) and then in this particular case another one for your confirm. You can hide internals of directive from whoever is consuming it, and it will allow you to modify DOM and not doing it in the controller

Comment: your question is unfortunately quite broad, because there are multiple ways to approach this problem.  Also, your assertion of `$scope` being "global" is a misnomer;  `$scope` is not global, there can be multiple `$scope` objects on a page, and they have an inheritance chain.

Comment: @Gonzolo are components able to do this rather than directives?